# How can i match value of two variables like match a variable and a string?

Tags: perl

During doing my home work, i faced to a problem.
the result is always "bye bye". How can I fix it?. Thanks.

```perl
$a = "abc";
$b = "asws.abc  sda .abb$sss";
if ($a=~$b){
     print "hello";}
else {
     print "bye bye";}
```

Comment: Some suggestions. Never use $a and $b - they are special variables which should be used in `sort` (see `perldoc perlvar`). Always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` pragmas to your scripts.

Comment: thank you so much, i will pay attention it

Answer (score 2):

`$b =~ $a` (which implies `$b =~ /$a/`) if the value of `$a` is a regex pattern.

`$b =~ /\Q$a/` if the value of `$a` is to be matched literally.